# Re-start an app game from zero

Tags: games, restart

I bought a new iPad and my wife is taking my old Mini. She really likes "Word Collect", but wants to start at the beginning, not at my level. I deleted the app, deleted the backup, but when I reload the game from iCloud it comes in at my old level, not zero.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **Customer Support** questions are outside of the scope of what can be asked here as defined in the [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

She probably needs to use her own iCloud account, not yours, to download the game.

You probably should also completely execute the **Erase All Content and Settings** command in `Settings > General > Reset` and start her off with a completely 'new' iPad and configure it for her use.

If you don't, she'll be using all your settings and data, which is why the game reverts to your level in the game.

Comment: Further: John can [set up Family Sharing](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201088) and add his & hers accounts to share purchases, so no fear in having to purchase the game twice (if the game is eligible, but most are).

Comment: I am so sorry I bothered you. In my question I stated what I had done, which was in the answer to the other question - those steps did not work for me.I am a 75 year old geezer trying to stay technically proficient. Apparently this site is a little more rigid than I need.

Comment: Allen - Above comment aimed at you.                                                                                Icon Daemon - Thanks for your answer.